# ALL CAPITAL Roman Numeral Chapter Style. How?

Tags: chapters, capitalization, roman-numerals

**Question revised:** What must I do to make "Chapter 1" display as "CHAPTER I", "Chapter 2" as "CHAPTER II", and so forth?

**Background and details:** This is a requirement for my thesis. I've searched a good while but not been successful in finding what I need without messing up what I already have. I found in the Wiki ([here](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/UsingMemoirInLyX#toc10)) about choosing different chapter styles, however, none of those listed are what I need.

I need "CHAPTER" to display in all capitals, and to use roman numerals for the number of the chapter (not the page number though). And it must not change how I've ([because of help from this awesome forum community](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153829/44093)) been able to get the page numbers in the correct places.

**Other details that may be relevant:**

- I'm using LyX version 2.0.6.
- Document class: book (Memoir).
- Modules selected: Custom Header/Footerlines.
- Page Layout -> Headings style: Default.
- Not two-sided.
- Margins: 4cm above, 3cm below, 4cm left, and 3cm right.
- LaTeX Preamble:

  ```
  \makeevenfoot{headings}{}{}{\thepage}
  \makeoddfoot{headings}{}{}{\thepage}
  \makeevenhead{headings}{}{}{}
  \makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{}

  \copypagestyle{chapter}{plain} % make chapter a page style of its own
  \makeevenfoot{chapter}{}{}{\thepage}
  \makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{}{\thepage}
  \makeevenhead{chapter}{}{}{}
  \makeoddhead{chapter}{}{}{}
  ```

**Question again:** What must I do to make "Chapter 1" display as "CHAPTER I", "Chapter 2" as "CHAPTER II", and so forth?

**Thank you** for your time and any help you provide!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without a minimal example it's difficult to say; but

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
```

should be all you need.

---

With `memoir`, there are several facilities one can exploit. Here's a solution that should accomplish your desires.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{headings}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{}

\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain} % make chapter a page style of its own
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{chapter}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{chapter}{}{}{}

\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\chapnamefont\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\kant[1]

\mainmatter

\chapter{A title}

\section{Something}

\kant

\end{document}
```

I added also a chapter in the front matter to show that the style is the same.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. "\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}" worked in the LaTeX Preamble. "\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}" didn't work in the LaTeX Preamble, but did work after I placed it right before the first chapter in "TeX Code". "\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}" has cause a problem, however, in that it makes other points in roman numerals as well (such as sections). That won't work. Is there a way to have the chapter numbers roman numerals, but the numbers in the sections and other places normal?

Comment: For example, instead of this (image of how it is currently): http://i.stack.imgur.com/oLBBZ.png I need this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sG8YZ.png

Comment: @Elijah Yes, it's possible to have what you ask for, but seeing the LaTeX preamble is needed. Of course, LyX will just make things more difficult to implement.

Comment: All in my preamble at this time is in the original post, plus the two lines of code/commands(?) you've provided here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with LyX and unfortunately I have problems installing it.
However, your problem can be solved by redefining the chapter command.

Add the following to your preamble in LyX:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
```

It will look something like this:
[image: Sample with Roman numerals]

If you want small roman numerals, simply use `\roman{chapter}`.

Comment: `titlesec` isn't really compatible with `memoir`.

Comment: You don't need `titlesec` to redefine `\thechapter`.