# Make amsbook consistently place page numbers in header or footer but not mixed

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, amsbook

I had used amsbook as a starting point for typesetting my thesis.

As you may be aware, amsbook `headings` page style is used for content pages, and has a running header containing the section title and page number.  Pages which start a new chapter or section use the `plain` page style instead, with no header and a page number in the footer.

While my university guidelines said

> For the preliminary pages – dedication (optional), acknowledgements (optional),
>   abstract, table of contents, list of tables, graphs, illustrations and preface (optional) –
>   use small Roman numerals (i, ii, iii, iv, v, ...). These may be placed either at the top or
>   the bottom of the page.
>
> For the text, use Arabic numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...) starting with page 1 (the first page of
>   the text itself). These may be placed either at the top or the bottom of the page.

It seems that "either at the top or the bottom" does not include the amsbook default.  I have been told

> I'm writing you to request minor changes to your submission
>
> - Page numbers may not change position but should be located in the same place throughout.

How can I fix this?

Comment: For anyone using `memoir` rather than `amsbook`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153829/how-to-change-page-number-location-on-all-pages-including-chapter-pages-withou?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By considering the default setup for `ps@plain` found in the `amsclass` documentation, I was able to change the `plain` pages to use header numbering (with no running title) as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{\ps@empty
 \def\@evenhead{%
   \normalfont\scriptsize
   \rlap{\thepage}\hfil
   }%
 \def\@oddhead{%
   \normalfont\scriptsize \hfil
   \llap{\thepage}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Basically, this is a clone of the `ps@headings` style but with the `\leftmark{}{}` and `\rightmark{}{}` invocations removed.

Comment: that is what i was going to suggest.  it's certainly the easiest way to change the header/footer style on "first pages", since it is used consistently.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: "easiest" it may be, but it still took me a few tries (while under time pressure) so I wanted to share the solution.

Comment: i'm glad you found it, and agree it's worth sharing (+1).  as i said, i would have suggested it, but the answer was already posted.