# Change location of page numbers (bottom, outer) without fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer

I cannot use fancyhdr because of a conflict. There is a similar question but the answer refers to the memoir class ([How to change page number location on ALL pages (including chapter pages) WITHOUT fancyhdr?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153829/how-to-change-page-number-location-on-all-pages-including-chapter-pages-withou)). I'm using the octavo class, so it does not apply. In my case, I do not need page numbers on ALL pages, only to change the position, the rest that octavo does is fine. Is there a tex way to do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{octavo}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=11cm,
inner=2cm]
    {geometry}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
        \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own page style. The code is mostly copied from the definition of page style `plain` (or `\ps@plain` to be more precise) from `source2e`, with slight modifications.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{octavo}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=11cm,
inner=2cm]
    {geometry}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ps@mystyle{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{%
    \reset@font
    \hfil
    \thepage
  }
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \def\@evenfoot{%
    \reset@font
    \thepage
    \hfil
  }
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{mystyle}
    
\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1]\marginpar{Hello}
    
\end{document}
```

Note that chapter (and maybe other objects as well) force plain style, so if you want this style in chapter pages, you can redefine the plain style instead of defining your own style:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{octavo}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=11cm,
inner=2cm]
    {geometry}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\ps@plain{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{%
    \reset@font
    \hfil
    \thepage
  }
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \def\@evenfoot{%
    \reset@font
    \thepage
    \hfil
  }
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
    
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter}
    \lipsum[1]
    
\end{document}
```

or you can redefine `\chapter`...

Comment: It works! Thanks!